# Php + mysql date issue

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

There is a table to hold last update date in database:

```
$syncDate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sync_info (last_sync TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '2003-01-01 00:00:00')";
```

And i'm updating it every time:

```
$dateUpdate = "UPDATE sync_info SET last_sync = NOW()";
```

Date is needed for data search:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM results WHERE InsertionDate BETWEEN '$startDateToSearch' AND NOW()";
```

where insertion date is also a timestamp in table.

The problem is stupid, but I can't get proper startDateToSearch from database. It always returns integer and I can't use it for data search in that way...

```
    $startDate = "SELECT * FROM sync_info";
$startFind = mysql_query($startDate, $GLOBALS['con']);
$array = mysql_fetch_array($startFind);
$row = $array[0];
$startDateToSearch = $row['last_sync'];
```

What I'm doing wrong???

Comment: Stupid question, already found an answer. How can I delete it???

Comment: Post your answer and accept it to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use SQL in one statement, such as

```
SELECT * from results, sync_info 
    WHERE InsertionDate BETWEEN sync_info.last_sync AND NOW()
```